# Java Multi Select - Add name / object pair in items (JList)

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to use `JList` to implement multi select option in Java Swing application, below is my code

```
// Create some items to add to the list
        String  listData[] =
        {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4"
        };


JList listbox = new JList( listData );
```

Now, i can see the multi select option look like below

[image]

I have added an action listener to get the selected item, but right now i can get only the text `"Item 1"`, but is it possible for me to associate an object with each item and get it
when user selects it?

**Update :**

Actually i am trying to sort a way to store items as like in html Object.getName() tag, so user views the name and when he selects it, with action listener we can get the object of the items selected..

Comment: please can you clarify whats `possible for me to associate an object with each item and get it when user selects it`

Comment: Please see my update in question.

Comment: What version of Swing are you running on Mac OS 9?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of instantiating a `JList` with a `String` array, instantiate it with an array of objects of your choice. Make sure that you override the `toString` method since that is what will be drawn. E.g.:

```
public class Item {

private int id;
private String name;

public Item(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}
```

If `Item` is a part of your data model, you add it to the JList model like this:

```
public class AppJList extends JFrame {

public AppJList() {
    super("JList model test");
    initUI();
}

public Item[] initModel() {
    Item[] model = new Item[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        model[i] = new Item(i, "text " + i);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    return model;
}

public JPanel initMainPanel() {
    JPanel jpanel = new JPanel();
    JList jList = new JList(initModel());
    jList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                JList list = ((JList) e.getSource());
                Item selected = (Item) list.getModel().getElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex());
                System.out.println("selected item with id: " + selected.getId());
            }
        }
    });
    jpanel.add(jList);
    return jpanel;
}

public void initUI() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(initMainPanel()));
    this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    this.pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // SwingUtilities.invokeLater
    // or
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AppJList().setVisible(true);;
        }
    });
}
}
```

If you want more control over list rendering, add a custom [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html):

```
     jList.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {

        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Item toBeRendered = (Item)list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
            return new JLabel(toBeRendered.getId() +":"+toBeRendered.getName());
        }
    });
```

in the `initMainPanel` method. For detailed explanations look at these tutorials:

- [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [JLists, data models, and cell renderers](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JList.html)

Answer (score 0):

See ListModel and the getModel() method in JList. You can use getElementAt(index)